# internet explorer fullscreen + kioskmode registry

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

when I use

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"FullScreen"=dword:00000001
```

it works correctly and hides the top status bar, but when I use it in combination with

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"DeviceKioskMode"=dword:00000001
```

it seems to ignore the fullscreen registry entry and show the status bar anyway. I'm running windows mobile 6.5 on a mc3190. How do I hide the status bar while in kiosk mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a program called `surefox/kioskIE`, it gets the job done for me :)